# PowerPivot is pulling blank values for cells in CSV that have a character length exceeding 8

Tags: powerpivot

I have a csv file that I'm trying to import into an excel data model (PowerPivot, not PowerQuery). One of the columns (Sales Doc) contains a numeric identifier, but some identifiers contain 8 characters, and others contain 10. It seems that PowerPivot is reading the column and assuming based off the first few rows that this column only contains 8 characters, and as a result anything exceeding that is imported with a null value. If I sort Sales Doc highest to lowest in the CSV it seems the issue is resolved, however I would prefer a solution within Excel. Any help is appreciated.